# Loading Data from SQL Server using jQuery and asp.net web-services

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, security

I want to load SQL data into a jQuery Graph plugin

**What I have read:**

Through out my research, everyone says that connecting directly to SQL Server from jQuery `.get` method is unsafe. What was suggested was that you rather connect to the database from a server side language such as asp.net.

**My question:**

Would it be safer then to create a web service that connects to the database and retrieves the data and then connect to that web service via jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is definitely that creating a web service (or ASP.NET API) is far, far safer. If you connect from the jquery then:

- The query is originated from the user's browser
- this means that either

  - the user is on the same domain and has to be given direct access
  - the web page has to contain a SQL logon and password, visible to View 
    Source
  - Either way the user has, or can easily work out how, direct access to your database
  - If this isn't on your intranet, your database is potentially exposed to every web user in the world
- also you have no opportunity to do any caching

Generally this is seen as pretty insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! You managed to answer some questions I didn't even know I should have asked.