# how to connect wp8 and above apps with external database (remote)

Tags: database, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application which needs to connect with an external database tables to perform insert and read operations. I have no experience related to this. I need some help from the beginner's view point.

Comment: succeeded with database connection using webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in fact very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964881/loading-data-from-sql-server-using-jquery-and-asp-net-web-services) because in that question the questioner wants to access a server-based database from random client devices - just like you do. The answer is the same.

The reason is that most databases listen on a particular port (it can usually be tailored, but they still listen on one port). That port is usually closed by firewalls so nothing external can get to it. Opening that port on the firewall is usually a bad idea as it is now exposed to the whole world.

The solution to this is to create a web service which runs under HTTP and accepts certain calls in given (limited) formats. Each separate call is passed certain bits of data and may pass back other bits of data - again in predefined formats. Within each call, the web service validates the data passed in (and possibly who is calling), makes appropriate database queries, and passes back to the caller whatever data is required.